# java.lang.SecurityException: Could not lock User prefs. Lock file access denied

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

When running Intellij Ultimate (version 2019.3.1) it throws this error:

```
Internal error. Please refer to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.SecurityException: Could not lock User prefs. Lock file access denied.
    at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.checkLockFile0ErrorCode(FileSystemPreferences.java:956)
    at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.lockFile(FileSystemPreferences.java:944)
    at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.sync(FileSystemPreferences.java:748)
    at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.flush(FileSystemPreferences.java:843)
    at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.syncWorld(FileSystemPreferences.java:483)
    at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$3.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:450)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)

-----
JRE 11.0.5+10-b520.17 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
```

What's the fix for this?

This *User prefs* error I presume is the reason why I have to setup and activate IntelliJ each time it is opened.

Comment: Check the filesystem permissions of the file it is trying to read or write. The user that is running the JVM does not have permission to that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~/.java/.userPrefs` directory, one of its subdirectories or the individual file has wrong permissions so that JVM is not able to write there.

This can occur if you've started some Java app from a different user (such as root) and the directory was created with the permissions for that user.

Another possible reason is that some other process is already holding a lock and manipulating the Java Preferences at the same time.

If it's some other process holding the lock, you can try to find and kill it.

If it's the permissions issue, the easiest solution is to just `sudo rm -rf ~/.java/.userPrefs` and then start the IDE again.

You can of course inspect the actual owner/permissions for this location and fix them using `chown`/`chmod` (recursively with the `-R` switch).

It's also worth checking the permissions of the `.java` directory itself and as the last resort you can delete it.

Comment: This somehow removed the problem, but the issue with setup/activate on every launch problem is still happening. I am using Jetbrains Toolbox btw.

Comment: IDE saves account login token there, so if the permissions are wrong or the file cannot be written for any reason, you'll be asked for the credentials every time. Try removing the entire `.java` directory.

Comment: Thanks this worked, removing the `.java` directory completely then re-run Toolbox and the IDE's